# Check if body exist from promise then

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

In PhantomJS when navigating, I'm getting the html here in `res` from the promise:

```js
return currentPage.property('content')
.then((res) => {

// here's the entire html
```

My question is simple: how can I check if body is not empty? I know that from Chrome's console I can do it like so:

```js
if (document.querySelectorAll("body").innerHTML === ""){
   console.log("Is empty")
```

But the problem is that I get `document is undefined` inside the promise because I'm not in Chrome's console. The same happens with jquery `$`.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("body").innerHTML` is `undefined`

Comment: OP's using phantomjs, from the tags. I assume s/he's trying to test responses in the body from a test unit or something similar.

Comment: That's the case, thanks @casraf

Comment: Sure. Can you update the question with the lines that create the request and return the promise? That would help.

Comment: @Defoe Can you show us the whole function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the best option, but sometimes is that simple:

```js
if(res.toString() === "<html><head></head><body></body></html>"){
                  console.log("Yes it's empty")
```

It's working now.